# Using DateTime with Null

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have this line of code here:

```
command.Parameters["@DateCompleted"].Value = items[i].DateCompleted.Equals("01/01/0001 12:00:00 AM") ? null : items[i].DateCompleted;
```

but I got this error:

```
Type of conditional expression cannot be determined because there is no implicit conversion between '<null>' and 'System.DateTime'
```

What I am trying to do is not use the 01/01/0001 Date and use null because the item is null.

Additional Code:

```
command.Parameters.Add("@DateCompleted", System.Data.SqlDbType.DateTime);
```

Comment: sounds like you need to take a look at the following [Nullable<T> Structure](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/b3h38hb0.aspx)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Simply cast the null to a `DateTime?`.  Also, assuming `DateCompleted` is a `DateTime` (it should be), then don't compare against a string, but against `DateTime.MinValue` instead.

```
command.Parameters["@DateCompleted"].Value =
    items[i].DateCompleted.Equals(DateTime.MinValue) 
        ? (DateTime?) null
        : items[i].DateCompleted;
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `DateTime?`

`command.Parameters["@DateCompleted"].Value = 
items[i].DateCompleted.Equals("01/01/0001 12:00:00 AM") ? (DateTime?)null : 
items[i].DateCompleted;`

Comment: Go with Matt's: I agree with the `DateTime.MinValue` approach.

Answer (score 0):

To use the ternary operator where one of the return types is `null`, the other return type has to be a nullable type, which `DateTime` is not, being a struct. What you could do is replace the `null` with `default(DateTime)`:

```
DateTime value = someCondition ? default(DateTime) : items[i].DateCompleted;
```